# kubernetes-dashboard I have got 404 error if I try to get access from external

Tags: istio, kubernetes-dashboard, istio-gateway

I'm trying to run dashboard in Kube v. 1.21 on AWS EKS

Kubernetes-dashboard work well using kubectl proxy.
But through Istio I have got 404 error.

`https://jazz.lnk/kubedash/dashboard/`

Perhaps URL `../dashboard/..` isn't correct? Also, I may get a mistake in configuration.

I run dashboard wit this configurations. https://gist.github.com/rmalenko/fc7c0f515cafa578f14dcafee1654f9c

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to run dashboard in Kube v. 1.21 on AWS EKS

Comment: Could you check logs for your ingress gateway and attach them to the question? Do you know with which component has problem with connection? Did you properly [expose your dashboard](https://help.sap.com/viewer/1246f58c6a74412580877af1f484f41a/2.6.latest/en-US/69a4f7bf0d904dc69dfb7be8ad1f97b5.html)?